# Access to requestContent within AfterRequest Script soapui

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I'm trying to simulate an asynchronous response on a webservice mock. The goal is to response a synchronous acknowledge message and then a delayed message back to the replyTo address. The approach I have selected uses mock service that will handle the acknowledge and then run a test case that will handle the processed message back to the replyTo. I'm using OnRequest Script to generate the acknowledged message and AfterRequest Script to run the test case that will emulate the delay and the response back to the replyTo.

So the question is which script object I can use to have access to the requestContent. I have seen examples using:

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
```

but the mockRequest instance is not available on AfterRequest, Which object I can use instead to have a holder with the request content?

Answer (score 2):

I did find that

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockResult.getMockRequest().requestContent )
```

do the trick, but now I find that running a test script in AfterRequest delays the synchronous response back, Why could this be happening? Isn't AfterRequest's script executed after the mock service response back? Do i have to explicitly execute something at Dispatch or at OnRequest in order to summit back the response before AfterRequest code being executed?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is really old question, but I just faced the same issue myself. I have no idea why it works as it works, but you can avoid the problem by accessing the request content in OnRequest, then store needed information to context and use the context in AfterRequest to get the information you need.